# Why doesn't type erasure work with arrays in Java?

Tags: java, type-erasure

I noticed we're unable to create arrays of a generic type in Java, like below:

```
public class ExampleClass<G> {
  private G[] genericArray = new G[arraySize];
}
```

I've read that this is due to the way Java handles generics, using type erasure. My understanding of type erasure is that the generic is just replaced by the most specific superclass container - so if we provide no bound, every instance of `G` is just replaced by `Object`.

Why can't this be done with the array, creating an array of type `Object`?

Comment: To be clear - is `Generic` a type variable?

Comment: Question edited for clarity. @AndyTurner

Comment: You can't use private in a constructor. Removed the constructor.

Comment: The facetious answer is that Java arrays were designed from the get-go but type erasure is a bodge to get generics working with older versions of Java. I’ll get my coat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this were allowed, and `G` were erased to `Object`, then the following wouldn't work:

```
ExampleClass<String> foo = new ExampleClass<>();
String[] array = foo.genericArray;
```

because `genericArray` would be an `Object[]`, not a `String[]`.

Comment: If `genericArray` in `ExampleClass` was never exposed to the client, and only intended for internal use would this be a non-issue?

Comment: The type system doesn't take visibility into account, so it makes no difference. If it's private, then there's nothing to stop you just declaring the array as its erasure, and casting manually.

Comment: @bag This defeats the purpose of generics. The entire point is that the client determines the type, in order to make your code reusable.